# how to email a dynamically created htmltable - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, system.net.mail

I have created an htmlTable and I want to email it:

```
Dim MyRow As New HtmlTableRow  
Dim cellCost, cellDisplayName, cellMoreInfo As New HtmlTableCell  
Dim tableAttributes As New HtmlTable  
tableAttributes.ID = "test"  

cellCost.InnerText = "$45.00"  
cellDisplayName.InnerText = "I am display Name"  
cellMoreInfo.InnerText = "I am more information"  

MyRow.Cells.Add(cellCost)  
MyRow.Cells.Add(cellDisplayName)  
MyRow.Cells.Add(cellMoreInfo)  

tableAttributes.Rows.Add(MyRow)  

PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tableAttributes)
```

When trying to email the `tableAttributes` global variable ... well that's where I run into troubles:
`Message.Body = tableAttributes.anything` <- fails.
    How can I create a dynamically generated table and then email it?

**UPDATE - solution was provided
Ha ha! it worked, you're awesome. This is what I created from your advice:

```
Dim SB As New StringBuilder()  
Dim SW As New StringWriter(SB)  
Dim htmlTW As New HtmlTextWriter(SW)  
Dim x As New HtmlTable  
x = Session("table")  
x.RenderControl(htmlTW)  

Dim sTable As String = SB.ToString()  

Response.Write("*" & sTable & "*")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Rendercontrol assignment to the table to export the table to a stringwriter which results in a string that can be included in your mail.

Comment: Awesome. I'm googling and giving that a shot!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do that... but I think your idea will work.

Answer (score 0):

When generating emails like this, I typically leap to use XML Literals. I wrote up a post discussing this at http://www.thinqlinq.com/default/Creating-HTML-emails-using-VB-9-and-LINQ.aspx.